# LG P500 Recovery Isuue

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, lg-optimus-one

I rooted my LG P500 and installed ROM Manager. I flashed ClockWorkMod Recovery (using the ROM Manager app). The problem is that when I boot to recovery I get a E: boot error "recovry" message at the bottom of my screen.

Device: LG P500

Android 2.3.3 [Software version - V20e]

Rooted with SuperOneClick

ROM - Stock (cant flash new ROMs because of this problem)

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try to re-flash the recovery image to your phone via fastboot.

Just googling a little, or directly on the xda-developers.com forum you can find all the info you need, including links to recovery images for your model:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=839

Comment: Any hints where to get working CWM recovery and how to do it on the LG P500?

Comment: I added a link to the forum.

Comment: http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.7-p500.img will be the official recovery image for the new baseband of LG P500 and the procedure explained for a different phone is in http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1647272

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, THANK YOU I WILL TRY THIS!
But please tell me, "reboot" for LG P500 means turning the device off and then turn it back on, or there is a key-combination that reboot the device? or should I download an app for that?
THANK YOU!